# Cocoa Scroll view bound setting(animate to specific point) is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

i am trying to move my scroll view to a specific point in my loadView method but facing some problem
i.e) work absolutely fine on Mac OSX 10.7 but not on 10.9

my code is

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1];
NSClipView* clipView = [self.scrollView contentView];

NSPoint origin = [clipView bounds].origin;

NSLog(@"******************");
NSLog(@"old Origin point is %f %f",origin.x,origin.y);
NSLog(@"********************");


origin.x = x - 1100;
origin.y = (483 - y) ;

[[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:origin];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

NSLog(@"********************");
NSLog(@"new Origin point is %f %f",origin.x,origin.y);
NSLog(@"********************");


clipView = [self.scrollView contentView];
origin = [clipView bounds].origin;

NSLog(@"********************");
NSLog(@"very new Origin point is %f %f",origin.x,origin.y);
NSLog(@"********************");
```

OutPut 
On OS 10.7

/******************
 old Origin point is -677.000000 -283.000000
 /********************

/*******************
 new Origin point is 311.000000 13.000000
 /*******************

/*******************
 very new Origin point is 311.000000 13.000000
 /*******************

But on OS 10.9

/*******************
 old Origin point is -677.000000 -283.000000
 /*******************

/*******************
 new Origin point is 311.000000 13.000000
 /*******************

/*******************
 very new Origin point is -677.000000 -283.000000
 /*******************

it means  [[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:origin]; not setting the new origin of scollview in OS 10.9

can someone tell me what i have to do more for that